# Python wildcard matching

Tags: python, wildcard

I have a python script that takes input using a pattern like this:
1** then takes multiple inputs after that like 100, 110, 011 ect.
I need to test to see if the imputed data matches the pattern, the * can stand for either a 1 or a 0. What is the best way to go about doing this? I'm fairly new to Python, so explanations would be helpful.

**Update**: added input and output example

Example of correct input and output:

input: 
**1 (pattern)
001, 101, 000
output:
001, 101

Comment: Convert the `*`s into `.`s and treat them as a regular expression?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put an example of correct and incorrect output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the input string and `replace` to generate a simple regular expression:

```
>>> '1**0*'.replace('*', '[01]')
'1[01][01]0[01]'
```

Now that can be used in whatever way you want:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '1**0*'.replace('*', '[01]')
>>> bool(re.match(pattern, '00000'))
False
>>> bool(re.match(pattern, '10000'))
True
```

If you aren't familiar with regular expressions, you might want to read a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) or two. But the fundamental idea is that any one of the characters between brackets is allowed. So a `[01]` matches either a 1 or a 0, as you requested in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `zip` instead of Regular Expressions.  It lines up all of the elements of both strings and lets you loop through each pair.

```
def verify(pat, inp):
  for n,h in zip(pat, inp):
      if n == '*':
          if h not in ('0', '1'):
            return False
      elif h not in ('0', '1'):
          return False
      elif n != h:
          return False
  return True
```

```
# Example use:
>>> verify('**1', '001')
True
>>> verify('**1', '101')
True
>>> verify('**1', '000')
False
```

---

A shorter way of doing it by @DSM.

```
def verify(n, h):
    return all(c0 == c1 or (c0 == '*' and c1 in '01') for c0, c1 in zip(n, h))

# or even shorter
verify = lambda n,h:  all(c0 == c1 or (c0 == '*' and c1 in '01') for c0, c1 in zip(n, h))
```

Comment: all(c0 == c1 or (c0 == '*' and c1 in '01') for c0, c1 in zip(patt, x))?  izip_longest could avoid '010' matching '01', but it's not clear whether the OP wants that or not.

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I didn't even think of different string lengths.  And I'll add the shorter version to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

regex can match the input you described:

```
import re
yourinput = "100";
matchObj = re.match( r'(1..', yourinput)
```

the dot is probably what you described with your star.

there are lots of tutorial, that e.g. describe what you can do with a matchobject, look here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm for a tutorial or here for the library documentation http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: This will not match 011 which was one of the OP's example valid outputs. Also, I think you're missing a ')'